# difference between slice declaration and initialization

Tags: go, initialization, slice

What is the difference between a and b? I know that reflect.DeepEqual considers them not equal and I know that a is nil. Are there built in functions that easily show the difference?

```
var a []foo
b := []foo{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fmt.Println(a == nil, b == nil)
```

prints `true false` (Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/E0nQP8dVyE). `a` is a nil slice, while b is just an empty slice. There isn't a lot of difference in practice, but usually, say in a function that queries a database, a nil slice means no result (due to error or something else), while an empty slice - that it could not find the information.

For the difference on the lower level, see Russ Cox's [Go Data Structures](http://research.swtch.com/godata) article.

Comment: Damn, forgot it's a slice. +1

Comment: In terms of [Go Data Structures](http://research.swtch.com/godata), it's clear that b's len/cap are zero but what does b's ptr point to? an underlying array of length zero?

Comment: @lf215 [Unsafe trickery](http://play.golang.org/p/HGnerzKXSX) shows that it points to some (apparently zero-sized) memory, but is overwritten as soon as you append anything to it.

Answer (score 2):

The [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for `a` makes it nil.

> **`nil`** for pointers, functions, interfaces, **slices**, channels, and maps.

As opposed to `b`, which is initialized as a [short declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).